# Highcharts bar with 2 series and multiple categories sorting by value issue

Tags: sorting, highcharts

I am working on a `bar chart` in Highcharts, having 2 series and multiple categories. By default chart is sorted with respect to categories. However I want to sort it by one of the series. Two series are year 22 and 23, I want to to sort by year 23 values. Here is the JS fiddle. Chart values are sorted by 23 but 22 series and categories remain at their own index and not sorting with series values of 23.

https://jsfiddle.net/saif_abbasi/e230ch4o/1/

I tried different variations of sorting options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can sort the values correctly by keeping the categories and the two value arrays separate.

The closest form I found to your fiddle is to extract categories in an array
and add them to each series data as `.name`. Note that you should use  `linkedTo: 'Mains'`, the colon prefix is used only for pseudo-ids like `:Previous`

```js
const companies = ["Alleg ompany", "Allmetnc.", "Amesh", "Colcoat", "Dr USi", "EO Systems LLC", "Frank g", "Gateway Ltd", "HFuller - Stan", "H.Ber Canada", "H.B. Ful Inc", "Helton Amer.", "Henen Coatings, Inc.", "ISS", "Laminat.", "Leading Edg", "Fastener Corp.", "New Wire Co.", "Qnex EPG", "Tri  Material (Vendor)", "V. Hi Inc.", "vv Corporation"];
Highcharts.chart('container-vbs', {
    chart: {
        height: 1000,
        type: 'bar'
    },
    
    title: {
        text: 'Vendor by Sales - YoY',
        align: 'left'
    },
    
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        type: "category",
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        lineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' '
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            borderRadius: '50%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            groupPadding: 0.1
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: -10,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 2022',
        data: [1353471, 28328225, 17299358.4, 1645332, 258734, 19318097, 10040147, 877155, 20012761, 3509712, 39352447, 25786925, 104624, 5293409, 0, 11486837, 19744104, 4105065, 25970082, 154851, 0, 11790044]
            .map((y, i) => ({name: companies[i], y})),
        linkedTo: 'Mains',
        showInLegend: true
    }, {
        id: 'Mains',
        name: 'Year 2023',
        data: [309808, 15939381, 97729712, 709014, 49635, 8903158, 5545960, 84136, 10767643, 2361102, 22395740, 10898253, 83012, 3316140, 16212, 5295329, 11237342, 1672293, 12391283, 0, 9277, 5881492]
            .map((y, i) => ({name: companies[i], y})),
        dataSorting: {
            enabled: true,
            matchByName: true
        }
    }
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container-vbs" class="chart-container"></div>
   
</figure>
```

Note that I changed the data for 2022, 3rd value from `172993584` to `17299358.4`, because otherwise the order of the two arrays was the same for the large values, so I couldn't be sure it is sorted by the second one and not by the first.

In my opinion, a cleaner solution would be obtained by using data as a table:

```js
const companies =  ["Alleg ompany","Allmetnc.","Amesh","Colcoat","Dr USi","EO Systems LLC","Frank g","Gateway Ltd","HFuller - Stan","H.Ber Canada","H.B. Ful Inc","Helton Amer.","Henen Coatings, Inc.","ISS","Laminat.","Leading Edg","Fastener Corp.","New Wire Co.","Qnex EPG","Tri  Material (Vendor)","V. Hi Inc.","vv Corporation"];
const data2022 = [1353471,28328225,17299358.4,1645332,258734,19318097,10040147,877155,20012761,3509712,39352447,25786925,104624,5293409,0,11486837,19744104,4105065,25970082,154851,0,11790044];
const data2023 = [309808,15939381,97729712,709014,49635,8903158,5545960,84136,10767643,2361102,22395740,10898253,83012,3316140,16212,5295329,11237342,1672293,12391283,0,9277,5881492];

Highcharts.chart('container-vbs', {
    chart: {
        height: 1000,
        type: 'bar'
    },

    data: {
        columns: [
        [null, ...companies],
        ['Year 2022', ...data2022],
        ['Year 2022', ...data2023]
      ]
    },

    // .... other options

    series: [
        {
            linkedTo: 'Mains',
            showInLegend: true
        },  
        {
            id: 'Mains',
            dataSorting: {
                enabled: true,
                matchByName: true         
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqpkzgjc/). Note that for this solution you need to also include `https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js`

Or, if you find highchart's `dataSorting` tedious, the table version allows
you to sort your data using directly javascript's sort, here's a [`data.rows`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.rows) table implementation:

```js
const companies =  ["Alleg ompany","Allmetnc.","Amesh","Colcoat","Dr USi","EO Systems LLC","Frank g","Gateway Ltd","HFuller - Stan","H.Ber Canada","H.B. Ful Inc","Helton Amer.","Henen Coatings, Inc.","ISS","Laminat.","Leading Edg","Fastener Corp.","New Wire Co.","Qnex EPG","Tri  Material (Vendor)","V. Hi Inc.","vv Corporation"];
const data2022 = [1353471,28328225,17299358.4,1645332,258734,19318097,10040147,877155,20012761,3509712,39352447,25786925,104624,5293409,0,11486837,19744104,4105065,25970082,154851,0,11790044];
const data2023 = [309808,15939381,97729712,709014,49635,8903158,5545960,84136,10767643,2361102,22395740,10898253,83012,3316140,16212,5295329,11237342,1672293,12391283,0,9277,5881492];

const data = {
    rows: [
        [null, 'Year 2022', 'Year 2023'],
        ...(companies.map((comp, i)=>[comp, data2022[i], data2023[i]]))
            .sort((r1, r2) => r2[2]-r1[2]) // sort by the 2nd column
  ]    
}

Highcharts.chart('container-vbs', {
    chart: {
            height: 1000,
        type: 'bar'
    },
    
    data,

    title: {
        text: 'Vendor by Sales - YoY',
        align: 'left'
    },
    
     xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        type: "category",
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        lineWidth: 0
    },
    
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' '
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            borderRadius: '50%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            groupPadding: 0.1
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: -10,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container-vbs" class="chart-container"></div>
   
</figure>
```